# css .to($('#home'), 1, {opacity:1})

Tags: html, css

I saw a code in my book about css. This segment of code struck me as unfamiliar and I couldn't find why it is so everywhere. The code is as following:

```
#mask, #hat, #movie {
    background-attachment:fixed;
}.to($('#home'), 1, {opacity:1});
```

"mask", "hat", and "movie" are ids of three paragraphs, and "to" is not a class name for any element. Now I am confused about its use. Can somebody please explain this for me. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a mixture of css and jQuery to me, it could be some CSS preprocessor I am not aware of, but it looks like a mistake to me

Comment: What book is this? I've never, in my 11 years of web development, have seen anything like this before. Might be some niche preprocessor as Dale says, but I think it's more likely a mistake.

Comment: first part is CSS, `.to()...` what is that?

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure it's not a mistake, because after applying this css, the transition between the background of paragraphs is pretty cool! So I think it may be a rare use? I have no idea.

Comment: @H.Niu can you post a jsfiddle of such use of css according to the book?

Comment: @H.Niu - Check about scss, sass, less.